# database row is changing every time I update the row

Tags: database, postgresql, flask

So I am using `postgres` type database and I have a function that updates rows in the database for some reason every time I change something it "pushes" the row to the end of the table rather than staying in the same position of where it was.
 this is an example of me updating the data (this is a part of the function):

```
users.query.filter_by(username = user).update(dict(computer_id = assign_value, level=level))
db.session.commit()
```

but for some reason whenever I see the `users` table I can see that whatever value I updated is getting pushed to the end of the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as an ordering on the records of a table. Internally, updating a record is handled as inserting a newer version and at some time delete the older version (if the trasaction completes,  the older version should not be needed again, at least not for newer transactions). From this point of view, it even makes some sense that the record is "moved" to the end of the table (eventhough the table does not have any start or end).

If you want to have a certain ordering, consider querying the data with an appropriate `ORDER BY` (or whatever function or options your framework uses to do this). If you query data and you do not specify an ordering, the retrieved records may be shuffled in any way. Do never rely on things like "If I only insert in this table, the data will always be returned in the same sequence as I inserted it" (eventhough this might be true under some circumstances).

Comment: It was weird to me because I think when I used SQLite it didn't change

Comment: This depends on the implementation of the DBMS, so this might indeed be true. But you should really never rely on things like this.